# (Adafruit_Python_DHT - Raspberry Pi) in get_platform RuntimeError: Unknown platform

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I have a **Raspberry Pi 4** connected with a DHT22 sensor, and I want to read data from my sensor.

So I installed the library [Adafruit_DHT](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT)

```
sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT
```

then, I navigate to the directory `Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/`, and then,

since I have a DHT**22** sensor connected to GPIO pi n° **4**,

I run

```
python AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
```

and I get

```
(lab_app) root@Raspberry100:/var/www/lab_app/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples# python AdafruitDHT.py 2302 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AdafruitDHT.py", line 41, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  File "/var/www/lab_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.8-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 94, in read_retry
    humidity, temperature = read(sensor, pin, platform)
  File "/var/www/lab_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.8-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 80, in read
    platform = get_platform()
  File "/var/www/lab_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.8-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 63, in get_platform
    raise RuntimeError('Unknown platform.')
RuntimeError: Unknown platform.
(lab_app) root@Raspberry100:/var/www/lab_app/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples# python AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AdafruitDHT.py", line 41, in <module>
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
  File "/var/www/lab_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.8-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 94, in read_retry
    humidity, temperature = read(sensor, pin, platform)
  File "/var/www/lab_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.8-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 80, in read
    platform = get_platform()
  File "/var/www/lab_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.4.0-py3.8-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafruit_DHT/common.py", line 63, in get_platform
    raise RuntimeError('Unknown platform.')
RuntimeError: Unknown platform.
(lab_app) root@Raspberry100:/var/www/lab_app/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples#
```

Since the traceback indicates

> 'Unknown platform.'

I did a little research on the github repository of Adafruit_Python_DHT library, and I found the script [`Adafruit_Python_DHT/Adafruit_DHT/common.py`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/Adafruit_DHT/common.py). 
 Here I see there is an If/elif structure `def get_platform()` that aims to identify the device calling the library, but there is value assignment only for RPi 1, 2 and 3, while RPi 4 is missing.
So I bet this is the reason why the error `unknown platform` occurs.

I navigated the library source code and I found out the directory [`Adafruit_Python_DHT/Adafruit_DHT/`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/tree/master/Adafruit_DHT) , in which the last commit says "included Raspberry Pi 4". 
Here is a module [`platform_detect.py`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/Adafruit_DHT/platform_detect.py) that seems to be designed to somehow "upgrade" the library in order to recognize Raspberry Pi 4.

So I tryed to "upgrade" my library by doing this:

In `(lab_app) root@Raspberry100:/var/www/lab_app/Adafruit_Python_DHT/Adafruit_DHT#`,

I run

```
platform_detect.py
```

And I don't get any output from the prompt, so I guess everything has gone right.

Then I navigate to the directory `Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/` and run again

```
python AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
```

but I still get the same error.

So how can I get data from a DHT22 sensor connected to GPIO pi n° 4 by using Adafruit_Python_DHT library?

Comment: I think you just need a more recent of the `Adafruit_Python_DHT` module. It looks like Pi 4 support was added about a year ago in [this commit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/commit/f2799f8408a4d3d105d9457fd9222a942bf57394).Trying install directly from github (`pip install git+https://...`).

Comment: Note though that the library was deprecated shortly after that, so if it is in fact broken it's unlikely to see any further fixes.

Comment: The commit you are talking about is actually the script I am using when I try to "upgrade" my library by running "platform_detect.py". But apparently it does not work...

Comment: pip3 -> use python3 (not python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank Tms91 for posting this solution as it helped find the heart of a problem I've been running into with the DHT22 sensor.

I was having issues reading the DHT22 sensor on a Raspberry Pi 4B.

The `platform_detect.py` file returns a value to the Adafruit_DHT routine `read_retry()` call to identify the platform being used (should return `3` for RPi4) when it tries to read temp and humidity.

A modification to [@tms91 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64254079/7658051) that worked for me was to add the BCM (Broadcom chip identifier) value for RPi 4B to the `platform_detect.py` file, (rather than failing out and supplying a value)

For example:

```
{your path}/Adafruit_Python_DHT/Adafruit_DHT/
```

Edit `platform_detect.py`: - in the function `pi_version()` [around line 112 ] add the BCM device value for RPI-4b (`BCM2711`) to the if/elif list of BCM types. For Raspberry Pi 4B, `BCM2711` is an updated value to check for:

```
# Adding the following elif to accommodate RPi4B Broadcomchip
elif match.group(1) == 'BCM2711':
    # Pi 4B
    return 3
```

No need to change the final else statement or edit the `common.py` file.

Next, return to the `{your path}/Adafruit_python_DHT/folder` and, as Tms91 suggested, run the `setup.py` again:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

to re-install the `platform_detect.py` file.

I'm guessing this might work for other similar platform errors if you're able to find the right value for your platform.

Comment: this worked for me thanks! One small thing I noticed: after following the steps, I had to change directory before trying to run read_retry(), because otherwise "import Adafruit_DHT" would take the local module (i.e not from site-packages).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a clean method, but it solved my problem.

By using Filezilla, I connected to my Raspberry Pi 4, I navigated to `Adafruit_Python_DHT/Adafruit_DHT/` and downloaded `platform_detect.py` and `common.py` on my local pc.

Then I edited these two files with *Notepad++* as follows:

**[platform_detect.py](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/Adafruit_DHT/platform_detect.py)**

At line 112-144 I substituted

```
else:
        # Something else, not a pi.
        return None
```

with:

```
else:
# Something else, like PI 4 MODEL B
# my personal changes to the code
    return 3
```

**[common.py](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/blob/master/Adafruit_DHT/common.py)**

at lines 62-63 I substituted:

```
else:
    raise RuntimeError('Unknown platform.')
```

with:

```
else:
    #raise RuntimeError('Unknown platform.')
    """Use Pi 2 driver even though running on Pi 4"""
    #my personal changes to the code, do it only if you are using a RPi 2, 3 or 4.
    from . import Raspberry_Pi_2
    return Raspberry_Pi_2
```

Then I saved the two files and uploaded them on the same directory on my RPi4, thus rewriting the older ones.

Then, with my command prompt, I run

```
sudo su
```

then I turn up the virtual environment and navigate to
`/var/www/lab_app/Adafruit_Python_DHT`, and here I run:

```
python setup.py install
```

And now the library gets installed without my prompt showing any error of platform detecting.

In the end I navigate to `/var/www/lab_app/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples` and run:

```
python AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
```

And the library works, returning me the values tracked by my sensor

> Temp=22.3*  Humidity=54.1%